# Applications of Kirchhoff's circuit laws to graph theory

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Is there a good survey on applications of Kirchhoff's circuit laws to graph theory or/and discrete geometry?

Examples:

- [Matrix tree theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem),
- [Squaring the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square),
- [Electrician’s  proof of Euler’s formula](https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/an-electricians-or-a-plumbers-proof-of-eulers-polyhedral-formula-2).

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment since it's not exactly what was asked: as an outsider, I found *Spectral Graph Theory* by Fan R. K. Chung (AMS, 1994) very informative.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly of help:

- [David G. Wagner, *Combinatorics of Electrical Networks*](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~dgwagner/Networks.pdf).
- [Pavlo Pylyavskyy, UMN Math 8680 Spring 2017, scribe notes (by students)](https://sites.google.com/site/pylyavskyy/8680-spring-2017). (Scroll down to the attachments section for the scribe notes. The papers are less closely related to the electrical networks theme.)

Answer (score 5):

I really liked the discussion of electrical circuits in the recent book ["Probability on Trees and Networks" by Lyons and Peres](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/prbtree.html). Chapters 2, 4 and 9 seem the most relevant to what you want.

Comment: Adding to this: Electrical network theory is extremely important in the theory of random walks on graphs and uniform spanning trees/forests, as discussed in Lyons & Peres. Some particular things worth mentioning related to USTs: 1. Kirchoff's effective resistance formula: This expresses the probability that the UST contains a given edge in terms of the effective resistance between the endpoints. 2. Transfer Current Theorem: Allows one to compute the probability that the UST contains any given set of edges in terms of electrical quantities, due to Burton and Pemantle.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical reference on all thinks Kirckhoffian is

*Doyle, Peter G.; Snell, J.Laurie*, Random walks and electric networks, The Carus Mathematical Monographs, 22. Washington, D. C.: The Mathematical Association of America. Distr. by John Wiley \& Sons, New York etc. XIII, 159 p. \sterling 22.00 (1984). [ZBL0583.60065](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0583.60065).

Comment: It does not seem to include things like counting trees...

Comment: Doyle and Snell is available online at http://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/walks/walks.pdf